# Proving this sequence is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a **positive** infinite series $a_n$ and I know that $a_n$$a_{n+1}$ converges to 1 and also that $a_n$$a_{n+2}$ converges to 1.

1. How do I prove that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence (without using limit arithmetics)?
2. How do I calculate $lim_{n->inf}a_n$ = ?

Thanks.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This question has the same given question, but this time the problem is proving the sequence as a Cauchy sequence and also calculating the convergence without using the methods used in the other question.